# select 100000187 from 100000187^Visit-NCH in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to select 100000187 from 100000187^Visit-NCH in sql?

Comment: It entirely depends on what your criteria for selecting that is...

Comment: Only Select numeric values from a column

Comment: Does that mean that if the column in question contained 100000187^Visit-9876-NCH, that the result should be 1000001879876?
In other words do you want to extract all the digits in a string, or just the number before the ^ character?
You are really asking about performing string operations on a column in an SQL query.
How predictable is the format of the string in this column? is it always <digits>^<text>?

Comment: There are many ways you could do that depending on the profile of the rest of the data in that column and what you want. i.e., Do you always want the first 9 chars? Do you want everything before '^'? Do you want all integers out of a string?  You might want to edit your question.

Comment: I want everything before '^' @JeffOrris

Comment: @Karthik Please see proposed answer

Answer (score 1):

I use below function for similar functionality.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Get_Integer_Part]
(
        @strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(256)
)
RETURNS bigint
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @intAlpha INT;
        SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric);
        BEGIN
            WHILE @intAlpha > 0
                BEGIN
                    SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(
                                               @strAlphaNumeric ,
                                               @intAlpha ,
                                               1 ,
                                               '');
                    SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric);
                END;
        END;
        RETURN RIGHT('000000000000' + ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric, 0), 12)
    END;
```

Usage:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_Get_Integer_Part('100000187^Visit-NCH');
```

Result:

```
100000187
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment in OP,

> I want everything before '^'

The following query is what you seek:

```
SELECT LEFT(<column>, CHARINDEX('^',<column>)-1) AS 'Stripped Column' FROM <table>
```

Comment: Do you mean `CHARINDEX('^',<column>)-1)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[REMOVE_NONINTEGERS](@TEXT VARCHAR(MAX))
       RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)

       AS
       BEGIN
       DECLARE @Reset BIT;
       DECLARE @Ret VARCHAR(8000);
       DECLARE @i INT;
       DECLARE @c CHAR(1);
       DECLARE @CharLength INT
       DECLARE @CHARSTART INT
       DECLARE @RESULT VARCHAR(MAX)
       SET @I = 1
       SET @CHARSTART = 0
       WHILE (@i <= LEN(@Text))
       BEGIN
            SET @CHARSTART = @CHARSTART + 1
            SET @RET = SUBSTRING(@TEXT,@CHARSTART,1)
       IF(@RET NOT in('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'))
        BEGIN
        SET @RET = ISNULL(@RET,'')
        SET @I = @I + 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN 
        SET @RESULT = ISNULL(@RESULT,'') + @RET
        SET @I = @I + 1
        END
        END

        RETURN @RESULT
        END

SELECT [dbo].[REMOVE_NONINTEGERS]('100000187^Visit-NCH')
```

[image]